# HttpClientFactory BadRequest?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dotnet-httpclient, httpclientfactory

I need to use `HttpClientFactory` for connection to external api. 
The code in `Startup.cs` looks this

```
public void SetUpHttpClients(IServiceCollection services)
{
        var loginEndpoint = Path.Combine(baseApi, "api/authentication);
        var fileExists = File.Exists(certificatePath);

        if (!fileExists)
            throw new ArgumentException(certificatePath);

        var certificate = new X509Certificate2(certificatePath, certPwd);

        services.AddHttpClient("TestClient", client =>
        {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseApi);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue(accept));
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("ApiKey", apiKey);

        var body = new { Username = username, Password = password };
        var jsonBody = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(body);
        var content = new StringContent(jsonBody, Encoding.UTF8, contentType);

        var loginResponse = client.PostAsync(loginEndpoint, content).Result;

        }).ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() =>
        {
            var cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
            var handler = new HttpClientHandler
            {
                CookieContainer = cookieContainer
            };
            handler.ClientCertificates.Add(certificate);
            return handler;
});
```

I've added this code in MessageController with HttpClientFactory,

```
public class MessagesController : Controller
{
    private readonly IHttpClientFactory _httpClientFactory;

    public ValuesController(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
    {
        _httpClientFactory = httpClientFactory;
    }

   [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult GetMessages()
    {
        var client = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient("TestClient");
        var result = client.GetStringAsync("/api/messages");
        return Ok(result);
    }
}
```

but when I try to connection and get messages from `HttpClientFactory` with I get this error:

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET, 404 - BadRequest

Comment: Quick question, why are you trying to make a request before completing the factory configuration? That Post will fail because you are trying to use the client while still configuring it.

Comment: Can you show where you actually need to use the client. In a controller or service class? The assumption here is that `SetUpHttpClients` is being called within `ConfigureServices`.

Comment: Yes, first I want to use in ConfigureServices and then call from controller.

Comment: Right well this feels like 
an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Clarify what it is you are actually trying to do and not just how you are trying to do it.Would allow for a more accurate answer.

Answer (score 2):

You trying to make a request before completing the factory configuration That Post will fail because you are trying to use the client while still configuring it.

The assumption here is that `SetUpHttpClients` is being called within `ConfigureServices`.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
    //...

    SetUpHttpClients(services);

    //...

    services.AddMvc();
}

public void SetUpHttpClients(IServiceCollection services) {
    var basePath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
    var certificatePath = Path.Combine(basePath, certPath);
    var fileExists = File.Exists(certificatePath);

    if (!fileExists)
        throw new ArgumentException(certificatePath);

    var certificate = new X509Certificate2(certificatePath, certPwd);

    //Adding a named client
    services.AddHttpClient("TestClient", client => {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseApi);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue(accept));
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("ApiKey", apiKey);
    })
    .ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() => {
        var cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        var handler = new HttpClientHandler {
            CookieContainer = cookieContainer
        };
        handler.ClientCertificates.Add(certificate);
        return handler;
    });
}
```

With the configuration done, the factory is available for injection into a controller or service class as needed.

The following example shows using the factory as a dependency to a controller.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class ValuesController : Controller {
    private readonly IHttpClientFactory factory;

    public MyController(IHttpClientFactory factory) {
        this.factory = factory;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get() {
        var client = factory.CreateClient("TestClient");
        var result = client.GetStringAsync("api/messages");
        return Ok(result);
    }
}
```

In the above the factory is used to create an instance of the named client. It will have all the configuration that was set during start up, which would include the client handler with certificate.

To be able to use the client during start up (which I would advise against), you would first need to build the service collection into a service provider.

```
var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
var factory = serviceProvider.GetService<IHttpClientFactory>();
var client = factory.CreateClient("TestClient");

var body = new { Username = username, Password = password };
var jsonBody = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(body);
var content = new StringContent(jsonBody, Encoding.UTF8, contentType);

var loginResponse = client.PostAsync("api/authentication", content).Result;

//...do something with the response
```

This can however have unforeseen results as the service collection would not have been completely populated at this stage in the start up process.

Comment: I've edited my first post with code. How can I fix this problem but I don't have to add credentials data in controller's method as you put in your first example. Thanks. What's wrong in my startup configuration fille ?

Comment: What do you prefer and advice me.? I want set correct way, first time I use HttpClientFactory

Comment: @enzodev we are having communication issue so having problems understanding the actual problem. how does `api/authentication` relate to `api/messages`. Could be because of explanation that we are not seeing things the same. Trying to help you best I can with the information you provided.

Comment: I need to get messages from endpoint api/messages, but precondition for that is correct authorization/login. I have separate endpoint for login (api/authorization) and if login response StatusCodeOK I need call api/messages endpoint from the same request. I have MessageController and method GetMessages().

Answer (score 1):

I've resolve this issue. `SetUpHttpClient` method look this:

```
public void SetUpHttpClients(IServiceCollection services)
{
    var basePath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
    var certificatePath = Path.Combine(basePath, CertPath);

    var fileExists = File.Exists(certificatePath);
    if (!fileExists)
        throw new ArgumentException(certificatePath);

    var certificate = new X509Certificate2(certificatePath, CertPwd);

    services.AddHttpClient("TestClient", client =>
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(BaseApi);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue(Accept));
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("ApiKey", ApiKey);

    }).ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() =>
    {
        var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
        handler.ClientCertificates.Add(certificate);
        return handler;
    });
}
```

The rest of code for login and messages I've added to service and call from controller.

**MessageClient.cs**

```
    public MessageClient(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
    {
        _httpClientFactory = httpClientFactory;

        _client = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient("TestClient");

        var body = new { UserName = Username, UserPassword = Password };
        var jsonBody = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(body);
        var content = new StringContent(jsonBody, Encoding.UTF8, ContentType);

        var loginEndpoint = Path.Combine(BaseApi, "api/authentication");

        _responseMessage = _client.PostAsync(loginEndpoint, content).Result;
    }

    public async Task<string> ReadMessages()
    {
        try
        {
            string messages = "";

            if (_responseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var messagesEndpoint = Path.Combine(BaseApi, "api/messages/");
                var cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
                var handler = new HttpClientHandler { CookieContainer = cookieContainer };
                var cookiesToSet = GetCookiesToSet(_responseMessage.Headers, BaseApi);

                foreach (var cookie in cookiesToSet)
                {
                    handler.CookieContainer.Add(cookie);
                }
                var messageResponse = await _client.GetAsync(messagesEndpoint);
                messages = await messageResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            }
            return messages;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw e.InnerException;
        }
    }
```

**MessageContoller.cs**

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult> GetMessages()
{
  var result = await _messageClient.ReadMessages();
  return Ok(result);
}
```

Thanks @Nkosi.

Comment: Some advice. Do not mix async await and `.Result`. It could cause deadlocks. Make `ReadMessages` async all the way through.